# AngularJS: Fetching data in loop with callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to fetch multiple json files in a loop. The data gets fetched, but in my callback function I'm left with the last key of the loop for each result.

Here is the caller:

```
deckbuilderApp.factory('DeckFactory', ['$http', '$rootScope', 'DataFactory', function($http, $rootScope, DataFactory) {

  var cardColors = {"white":{}, "blue":{}, "black":{}, "red":{}, "green":{}, "colorless":{}};
  var cardColorsCheck = {"white":true, "blue":true, "black":true, "red":true, "green":true, "colorless":true};

  return {
    fetchCardColors: function() {
      for (key in cardColors) {
        if (cardColors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          DataFactory.cardColors(key, function(cardIds) {
            console.log("GOT COLORS FOR " + key);
            cardColors[key] = cardIds;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the callee:

```
deckbuilderApp.factory('DataFactory', function($http) {
  return {
    cardColors: function(color, callback) {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'js/cardColors/' + color + '.json'
      }).success(callback)
    }
  }
}
```

The data that gets fetched is legit, but the log line always prints "GOT COLORS FOR colorless" the last of the keys.

Comment: it's because your `cardColours` function is async. The callback is being invoked after the loop finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as evaluating

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, 0)
}
```

You will get 100 times number 100 logged into the console.

This is because of the contents of your for loop are async.

To prevent this you may use `let` (closure, iife, etc.):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, 0)
    })(i)
}
```

This pattern is so common that in new JavaScript (ES6) there is a `let` keyword:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, 0)
}
```